# WebGL blendFunc bug or misunderstanding?

Tags: webgl, alphablending, glblendfunc

I'm trying to draw a semi-transparent black triangle on a black background.

[image]

Here's my sample: http://codewithoutborders.com/posted/blend.html

The blendFunc is set and enabled (line 151):

```
gl.blendFunc(gl.SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
gl.enable(gl.BLEND);
```

The buffer is cleared to black (line 129):

```
gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

The shader fills with semi-transparent black (line 10):

```
gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, .5);
```

I would expect the triangle to be black, since the docs state that

```
result = {foreground}*sourceAlpha + {background}*(1-sourceAlpha)
       = (0,0,0,.5)*.5 + (0,0,0,1)*.5
       = (0,0,0,.75)
```

which is black, right?

so where does the grey come from?

Answer (score 4):

(how embarrasing. answering my own question 3 minutes after posting, but not before significant hair loss)

the grey comes from the white background of the HTML page showing through after 'punching' a 3/4-transparent hole though the otherwise-black canvas.

adding

```
style="background:black;"
```

to the  tag solves the problem.

[gman's comment, below, is a better fix]

Comment: You can also create your canvas with no alpha using canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl", {alpha:false});

Comment: how is the gray color calculated?